# Dropbox Sync using Mac command line

Tags: dropbox

Is there a way to sync dropbox using the command line. I have two dropbox accounts, I have a second dropbox folder installed but my mac wont allow me to mount both of them at the same time.
So I was hoping I could use my command line to sync it and some other simple commands.
I'm using a mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox has [Command Line Interface](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli), however I'm afraid you won't be able to use it that way. You'll need something more sophisticated, something based on [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start).

Comment: Is there a version of the CLI which talks to a OS X dropbox process rather than the linux daemon?